# RecyclerView duplicates some UI components

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement a `RecyclerView` in my app but some UI components in my `RecyclerView` keep repeating themselves when I scroll. It might be an issue with cache but I haven't implemented any logic for cache of UI elements. I'm also using the Picasso library.

Here's my code:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<CardViewBean> mListItemsCard;
    Activity mActivity;
    CardViewBean itemCardView;
    ChatMessageDTO chatMessageDTO;
    List<EventGalleryDTO> eventGalleryDTOs;
    private static final String PICASSO_CACHE = "picasso-cache";

    public Adapter(Activity activity, List<CardViewBean> listItemsCard) {
        mListItemsCard = listItemsCard;
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(mActivity, LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_adapter, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mActivity);
        itemCardView = mListItemsCard.get(position);
        holder.txtEventName.setText(itemCardView.getEventName());
        if (itemCardView.getMessageCount() > 0) {
            holder.txtChat.setText("(" + itemCardView.getMessageCount() + ")");
        }
        if (itemCardView.getImageCount() > 0) {
            holder.txtGallery.setText(String.valueOf(itemCardView.getImageCount()));
        }
        chatMessageDTO = getChatMsgDTO();
        String imagePath = mListItemsCard.get(position).getImagePath();

        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(imagePath)) {
            File file = new File(imagePath);
            if (file.exists()) {
                setCreatorImage(file, holder);
            } else {
                holder.ivEventImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.placeholder);
            }
        }

        if (chatMessageDTO != null) {
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(chatMessageDTO.getMessage())) {
                holder.txtLastMessage.setText(chatMessageDTO.getMessage());
            }

            String time = "";
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(chatMessageDTO.getDateTime())) {
                String dateArr[] = chatMessageDTO.getDateTime().split(" ");
                if (dateArr.length > 1) {
                    if (dateArr[1].contains(":")) {
                        time = dateArr[1].substring(0, dateArr[1].lastIndexOf(":"));
                    } else {
                        time = dateArr[1];
                    }
                    holder.txtLastMessageTime.setText(time);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mListItemsCard.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (add a else statement):

```
if (itemCardView.getMessageCount() > 0) {
    holder.txtChat.setText("(" + itemCardView.getMessageCount() + ")");
}

else {
    holder.txtChat.setText("")

}

if (itemCardView.getImageCount() > 0) {
    holder.txtGallery.setText(String.valueOf(itemCardView.getImageCount()));
}
else {
    holder.txtGallery.setText("")
}
```

Comment: It worked to some Extent, but the Images from setGalleryImages are still repeating.

Comment: Also, i'm getting an Exception java.lang.illegalStateException: the specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent.